# what is the fasted way to call Lua from C?

Tags: c, lua

I have an HTTP server that needs to handle HTTP requests from Lua code. From C code, I call some Lua C API this way (idea comes from [**here**](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_c_calls_lua.htm)):

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaL_loadfile(L, "some.lua");
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);   /* preload */
lua_getglobal(L, "handle");
lua_pushstring(L, "http_request");
lua_pcall(L, 1, 1, 0);
lua_close(L);
```

This bunch of code is run for every HTTP request. In *multi-thread* worker context, this code has a considerable performance cost (from 20000tps to 100tps). I wonder **is there was more efficient way to call Lua code from C**?

---

***Update***

When I comment out all these Lua C API calls, I can make a 20000tps. But when open this API calling, 100tps. When make some changes in *some.lua* (remove the `require` call, only load a empty Lua file), then performance comes to about 15000tps.

So, at lease, these API calling cost about 5000tps, how to make this API calling more faster?

Comment: Yap. Move everything outside of the function except `lua_pcall()`.

Comment: Can multi-thread share the same `lua_State` ?

Comment: All `lua_` calls to a particular `lua_State` must not occur concurrently. This is why it's common to have one Lua state per thread.

Comment: After the update: I have no good answer, but some tips. Make sure the lua interpreter is in your same source tree, and enable link-time optimizations for your whole program so that lua api calls can be inlined... Also, check the multi-threading aspect and your cache usage (shared state between threads, too-many threads per processor, active set)...consider that as you micro-benchmark, you move out of real-world scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a thread-safe queue per Lua state and have the state pop from the queue in an infinite loop. If the queue is empty, have the state wait on a condition that is triggered upon insertion into the queue.
I suggest LuaJIT, as it will optimise the raw threading API calls to approach near-C speeds.

Unless you are handling large amounts of HTTP requests, this will not benefit you significantly (as mentioned by dsign).

Note: this approach involves the reuse of Lua states for multiple requests. If this is a security problem, you might be able to do something with per-session Lua states with an expiration timeout... but I'm not sure.
(It'd be an interesting experiment in stateful server-client partnerships! You could use the Lua state to hold the user's entire session and then resume from sleep when there's a new request... which would be fast.)

Comment: @ Deco: According to your answer, there are two options, plugin a `lua_State` (as `void *plugin` field in their definition)into each client or worker, no trigger or queue related constructs(queue may need mutex operation). While in client, it seems like a session, and in worker seems reuse the `lua_State` for various client accepted by the worker, maybe got some safety problems. You remind me this, thanks a lot.